# Is the button placement in Linkedin's new invitation dropdown correct?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, navigation, user-behavior, icons

Accidentally I deleted one of the invitation in Linkedin. The problem there was the delete invitation button is aligned to the icon which opens new invitation drop down.

Is it a right UX practice? Should we follow this just because reputed companies like linkedin are doing it?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the correlation you're seeing between the button in the nav bar and the delete buttons in the list. Do you mean you interpreted the button in the nav bar as a header for the delete buttons below?

Comment: @MattObee the way I understand it, the OP's "accidental" deleting means his finger slipped to the deletion icon unintentionally, presumably starting from the button which opens the invitation list. Or, maybe he was aiming for the upper icon but hit the lower one because it is below it. Anyway, I think the aligning he shows is not supposed to suggest any semantic connection.

Comment: @MattObee What i think that the button for accepting should be first & delete button should be at right. What do you think?

Comment: @RumiP. After a dropdown open a user always moves the cursor vertically to the dropdown, in Linkedin case it's the "delete invitation" button an user first encounter. Don't you think its dangerous?

Comment: @SurendraVikramSingh I have no opinion on the vertically moving cursor, as I haven't had the chance to play with this design (I don't use a mobile LinkedIn application). As for the left vs. right, this is a platform convention as Benny Skogberg explained.

Answer (score 1):

It's [platform dependent according to Nielsen Norman Group](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ok-cancel-or-cancel-ok/).

> **Summary**: Should the OK button come before or after the Cancel button? Following platform conventions is more important than suboptimizing an individual dialog box.

That said, It's correct on Apple devices, but not OK on Android/Windows Phone devices.

Comment: But after a dropdown open a user always moves the cursor vertically to the dropdown, in Linkedin case it's the delete invitation button an user first encounter. Don't you think its dangerous?

Comment: @SurendraVikramSingh Well, It's not a cursor - its the finger. And before pushing anything, I the user usually checks where to push. Especially in a critical situation like this. Do I or don't I accept this invitation to connect.

Comment: But it's a screenshot from linkedin web app.

Comment: @SurendraVikramSingh From the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_detection), it's posible to determine which device is running the web app.